# Why won't perl/ptkdb honor the ptkdb*<property> entries I have in .Xdefaults?

Tags: perl

PLATFORM=linux_2.6.32_64
ptkdb: perl-5.18.2-gcc481/lib/5.18.2

I'm trying/failing to get ptkdb to use the font def I placed in .Xdefaults for it.  This is the entry in .Xdefaults...

```
ptkdb*font:                        -adobe-courier-medium-*-18-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

I "constructed" that font name using "xfontsel" and am assuming it's valid.
I then ran "xrdb ~/.Xdefaults"
I copied ~/Xdefaults to ~/Xresources

When I run perl using the debugger (perl -d:ptkdb myscript.pl) it sticks to the same, small font that I want to change.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

My bad.  I transcribed the font name from xfontsel incorrectly.  This worked...

```
 -adobe-courier-medium-r-normal-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

(I missed the "-normal-")